# Unable to send Authorization header as server response 401

Tags: swift3

There is no compilation error in the below code.

However, I got the message from server : 401

This means the server unable to receive the Header which I sent.

However   My Auhtorization header  contain this value:
     var strToken = strToken1 + ", " + strToken2 + ", Basic " + strBase64Credential

**Update:**

strBase64Credential is :  Username and password

strToken1 and strToken2 are not username and password

```
What I did wrong and Why server did not receive the header values?


in plist : I added this :

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
 </dict>




 var request = URLRequest(url: StrURL)

 var strToken = strToken1 + ", " + strToken2 + ", Basic " + strBase64Credential 

 request.httpMethod = "GET"
 request.setValue("application/json", forHttpHeaderField:"Content-type")

 request.setValue(strToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

 let session = URLSession.shared

 session.addTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in 

    if let response = response {

     print(response)
    } else {

      return 

    }

   if let data = data{

     //-- handle data here

   }

}.resume()
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. strToken1 as like userName and strToken2 as a password. This format used for a basic authentication process.

```
  let basicAuthString = "\(userName):\(password)"
  let utf8str = basicAuthString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  let base64EncodedString = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))

  request.addValue("Basic \(base64EncodedString!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: var strToken = strToken1 + ", " + strToken2 + ", Basic " + strBase64Crendential  where strBase64Credential is Username: Password

Comment: Why you need strToken1 and strToken2 for creating authentication string?
For authorization username and password is not enough?

Comment: strToken1 and 2 are data which required by the server.

Comment: Is it related to authentication? If not then I will update my answer. If strToken1 and 2 are required then send as a different param with a different key. Only change `var strToken = "Basic " + strBase64Credential`   in your code for authentication.

Comment: strToken1 and 2 are data required by the server, and they are not used for authentication. But should include in the Authorization header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159875/discussion-between-faysal-ahmed-and-milkbottle).